# from torch.utils.cpp_extension import load error in loading the cpp file

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, torch

My main code to call my cpp function looks something like this. I am trying to run a cpp file using python.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

from torch.utils.cpp_extension import load


gcc_path = os.getenv('CC', default='/bin/gcc')

if not Path(gcc_path).is_file():
    raise ValueError('Could not find your gcc, please replace it here.')


my_extension = load(
    name='_pvcnn_backend',
    extra_cflags=['-O3', '-std=c++17'],
    extra_cuda_cflags=[f'--compiler-bindir={gcc_path}'],
    sources=['/shared/home/v_ashwin_nair/pc2/projection-conditioned-point-cloud-diffusion-main/experiments/model/pvcnn/modules/functional/src/ball_query/ball_query.cpp'],
    verbose=True
)
```

Now, I wish to run my cpp file which looks like this

```
#include "ball_query.hpp"
#include "ball_query.cuh"

#include "../utils.hpp"

at::Tensor ball_query_forward(at::Tensor centers_coords,
                              at::Tensor points_coords, const float radius,
                              const int num_neighbors) {
  CHECK_CUDA(centers_coords);
  CHECK_CUDA(points_coords);
  CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(centers_coords);
  CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(points_coords);
  CHECK_IS_FLOAT(centers_coords);
  CHECK_IS_FLOAT(points_coords);

  int b = centers_coords.size(0);
  int m = centers_coords.size(2);
  int n = points_coords.size(2);

  at::Tensor neighbors_indices = torch::zeros(
      {b, m, num_neighbors},
      at::device(centers_coords.device()).dtype(at::ScalarType::Int));

  ball_query(b, n, m, radius * radius, num_neighbors,
             centers_coords.data_ptr<float>(),
             points_coords.data_ptr<float>(),
             neighbors_indices.data_ptr<int>());

  return neighbors_indices;
}
```

This the error which I am getting. I am using python 3.9 and I have installed the correct versions of gcc and g++.

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: /shared/home/v_ashwin_nair/.cache/torch_extensions/py39_cu117/_pvcnn_backend/_pvcnn_backend.so: undefined symbol: _Z10ball_queryiiifiPKfS0_Pi
```